# Test access controller in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, controller, jasmine, karma-runner, directive

I need to test methods from a controller into a directive.

```
APP.angular.directive('miniCrud', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require:"ngModel",
        scope: {
            miniCrudHeader: '@',
            miniCrudConfig: '=',
            modelValues : "=ngModel"
        },
        templateUrl: 'templates/mini-crud.html',
        controller: ['$scope', 'lodash', 'filterFilter', 
            function($scope, _, filterFilter){

                $scope.vm = {
                    getValue: function(item, index) {
                        var prop = $scope.miniCrudConfig.fields[index].name;
                        return item[prop];
                    }

                // some other methods
                }
            }
        }]
     };
});
```

How can I acess $scope.vm.getValue()?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know how to test a directive. Since your directive creates an isolated scope you have to use the `isolatedScope` function on the object returned by [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

Once you create an html directive element in your test, compile it and link it to a scope.  You can then use the compiled element to get hold of isolated scope

```
var s = angular.element(compiledAndLinkedDOM).isolatedScope();
s.vm.getValue();
```